# Multiple objects, geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there a way to output multiple objects from Geometry Nodes? To, for example ,the same collection but as separate objects. I have a workflow where I start with a box to create buildings, but I would like do divide façade/roof/windows into different objects, to apply different shaders to them. Since I am making a lot of buildings it would be nice it I could avoid doing the separation manually.

Any tips, anyone?

Comment: No, if the _Geometry Nodes_ modifier is on a single object, the output will be a single object. Even if you have multiple instances in there and use _Realize Instances_, they are all part of the single object. Like when you are using an _Array_ modifier. If you apply it, you have an array of meshes, but they are all part of the single object that had the modifier. Probably there will be possibilities by giving your object meshes attributes wtih which you can distinguish them to maybe create a python script for separating them afterwards. But python is nothing I could help with, sorry.

Comment: Geometry Nodes doesn't operate on scene level, it can't create multiple objects or colections. This sounds like the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you can assign different materials in Geometry Nodes without separating into different objects. Why do you require separation?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I am exporting the model as a FBX to a different program where I will be assigning the materials and use the different parts (doors/windows/walls) to procedurally generate variations of the building. I will try to assign different materials in Blender and hopefully that info will transfer so I just can replace those materials without the separation, but I will probably still need some parts to be different objects.

Comment: I've read that some people make node setups adequate for exporters that realize instances in such way they can be exported as separate objects, though I'm not sure exactly how.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using object references as instance ("As Instance" checkbox is checked), yes you can.
 While the object is selected go to Object > Apply > Make Instances Real. All the instances become separate objects.
[image]
[image]
[image]

 * You can also check this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/Y_0GAvR6Re8?t=771) for an example.